# Is it possible to erase ON path in photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I have a path and I was wondering if it were possible to erase on along this path. Anyone ever heard of such a thing?

Comment: What do you mean, "on along this path"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite possibly an easier way but one way that springs to mind is:

- Create a new layer, **all white**,
- Stroke your path onto this layer, using the **black/grey** brush/pen of your choice,
- Copy this layer to the clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
- Hide or delete this layer
- Go to the layer you want to erase the path
- Enter Quick Mask Mode
- Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)
- Exit Quick Mask Mode
- Convert the selection to a mask (Layer -> Layer mask -> Reveal Selection)

This method has the advantage that you can selctively edit the layer mask in case you do not want to erase along the entire path.

Note: If you want to erase the background using this method, you'll need to promote it to a layer first (Layer -> New -> Layer from background)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed erase along a path. To do so (instructions for CS4):

1. Select the layer you want to erase content from
2. Draw a path with the **Pen** tool
3. Open the **Paths** pane (available from the Window menu if it's not visible)
4. In the top-right corner of the **Paths** pane is an options menu, click it
5. Select **Stroke Path...** from the menu
6. From the dialog's dropdown select the **Eraser** tool, click OK

If the result isn't quite what you expect, undo the last action, select the Eraser tool from the toolbar (or hit default hotkey <kbd>e</kbd>) and change the brush style and size accordingly, repeat steps 4-6.